# Java class within a class

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay I compiled my Script, which output 5 classes, BankValueGUI, BankValueGUI$1, BankValueGUI$2 & so on. I accidentally deleted the source files, so I've had to decompile it, however it hasn't decompiled into 1 .java file, it's decompiled into 5.. Upon attempting to place the Class's into the main class again I continue to recieve errors, Here's the MAIN source:

```
package scripts.BankChecker;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class BankValueGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
  private javax.swing.JButton inputFileButton;
  private JFileChooser inputFileChooser;
  private javax.swing.JTextField inputFileField;
  private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
  private javax.swing.JButton startButton;

  public BankValueGUI()
  {

    initComponents();

  }

  private void initComponents()
  {


    inputFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    inputFileField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    inputFileButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    inputFileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    inputFileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Choose this file");
    inputFileChooser.setApproveButtonToolTipText("Make sure there is one account per line, in user:pass format");
    inputFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

    inputFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose the text file containing accounts to check");
    inputFileChooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", new String[] { "txt", "text" }));
    inputFileChooser.addActionListener(new BankValueGUI$1(this));





    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    jLabel1.setText("Input File:");

    inputFileField.setEditable(false);
    inputFileField.setText("The file containing accounts to check");

    inputFileButton.setText("Browse");
    inputFileButton.addActionListener(new BankValueGUI$2(this));





    startButton.setText("Start");
    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    startButton.addActionListener(new BankValueGUI$3(this));





    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addContainerGap()
      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addGap(8, 8, 8)
      .addComponent(jLabel1)
      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
      .addComponent(inputFileField, -2, 331, -2)
      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
      .addComponent(inputFileButton)
      .addGap(0, 12, 32767))
      .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addComponent(startButton, -1, -1, 32767)
      .addContainerGap()))));

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addContainerGap()
      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
      .addComponent(jLabel1)
      .addComponent(inputFileField, -2, -1, -2)
      .addComponent(inputFileButton))
      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
      .addComponent(startButton)
      .addContainerGap(-1, 32767)));


    pack();
  }

  private void inputFileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    inputFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
  }

  private void inputFileChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    inputFileField.setText(inputFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    startButton.setEnabled(true);
  }

  private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ScriptWorker.inFile = inputFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    ScriptWorker.guiDone = true;
    dispose();
  }







  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : ) {
        if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BankValueGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BankValueGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BankValueGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BankValueGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new BankValueGUI$4());
  }
}
```

AND HERE's THE CLASS'S

```
  class 1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
            BankValueGUI.access$0(BankValueGUI.this, evt);
        }
    }

  class 2 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
            BankValueGUI.access$1(BankValueGUI.this, evt);
        }
    }

  class 3 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
            BankValueGUI.access$2(BankValueGUI.this, evt);
        }
    }

  class 4 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           new BankValueGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

TAKE NOT I'm USING AN EXTENDED LIBRARY SO TRIBOTs LIBRARY SO THERE WILL BE MORE ERRORS ON YOUR END REGARDING TRIBOT RELATED CONTENT.

Comment: Have you checked your Recycle bin ;) ?

Comment: Did you name your classes 1 - 4?

Comment: Yes i've tried recuva tool aswell, no luck :/

Comment: You can often recover lost source files in Eclipse by right clicking on the Project and selecting 'Restore from Local History...'

Answer (score 2):

> however it hasn't decompiled into 1 .java file, it's decompiled into 5

That's because it's not 1 class.

Anonymous classes are compiled to classes named `ContainingClass$Number` by convention, but there is no reason why you can't create a class called that explicitly - so there is no way to know that `BankValueGUI$1` is a nested class and not a top-level class with the same name.

> Upon attempting to place the Class's into the main class again I continue to recieve errors

Class names must be valid Java identifiers. Java identifiers cannot start with digits. (See [JLS Section 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)).

It's pretty dubious that the decompiler doesn't create a class called `BankValueGUI$1` or whatever, but that is simply a bug (or, at least, a "feature") in the decompiler.

Answer (score 2):

In the JVM there is no concept of inner classes. The java compiler javac, compiles inner classes as separate classes like BankValueGUI$1 and so on and each of these non static classes have a member this$0 which refers to the outer class instance.

So each of the inner class is a separate class by itself (though you can't use such names for your classes as they won't get past the compiler). Class names and method names must be valid Java identifiers (JLS Section 3.8).

As for your errors, take a look at:

```
class 1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
            BankValueGUI.access$0(BankValueGUI.this, evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Here  access$0 is a method added by javac to support inner classes accessing the outer class instance's fields and access$0 is not a valid name. Obviously you will get an error.

It is not an easy task to decompile your class files and expect to have working code with minimal changes. You may have to change a lot. More specifically you have to make all of these classes inner classes.